# copying from a std::string to a char array and null-terminating the result

Tags: c++, string

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++03 application where I want to copy from a std::string to a char array, but I need the char array to be null terminated even if it must truncate the string to do so.

This, for instance works as desired:

```
inline void CopyAndNullTerminate( const std::string& source, 
                                  char* dest, 
                                  size_t dest_size )
{
    source.copy( dest, dest_size );
    using std::min;
    char* end = dest + min( dest_size - 1, source.size() );
    *end = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    enum{ MAX_STRING_SIZE = 15 };
    char dest[ MAX_STRING_SIZE ];
    std::string test = "This is a test";

    CopyAndNullTerminate( test, dest, MAX_STRING_SIZE );

    assert( strcmp( test.c_str(), dest ) == 0 );
    return 0;
}
```

example: http://ideone.com/0EBYb

Is there a shorter, more efficient method of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, use [`strncpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/), defined in `cstring`:

```
void copyString(const std::string& input, char *dst, size_t dst_size)
{
    strncpy(dst, input.c_str(), dst_size - 1);
    dst[dst_size - 1] = '\0';
}
```

Note that for some implementations of `std::string` (as pointed out by @K-ballo), this may be shorter, but less efficient. This is due to the fact that `std::string` is NOT guaranteed to be implemented using C-syle strings, although for most situations that is probably the case.

Comment: This has the unfortunate side effect of having to construct a valid null terminated C string for those implementations of `std::string` that don't use that as the internal representation.

Comment: @K-ballo true, but for most implementations, I assume that that would be the implementation used...

Comment: While this method is shorter, it _may_ be **less** efficient. You should point that out in your answer.

Comment: why is it faster than "source.copy( dest, dest_size );"?

Comment: @Unni it may or may not be. `strncpy` can be inlined, and written completely in assembly, which could make it faster than the STL's `copy` function. The drawback to this is that if the string wasn't implemented using C-style strings, it must internally create a new string as a buffer.

Comment: @K-ballo, are you aware of a `std::string` implementation that doesn't use a null terminated array as its internal representation? Or is this more of a theoretical concern?

Comment: The real reason this can be inefficient is that it fills the buffer with nulls, even though only one is necessary.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: Yes, I do know one, the _awkward yet standard compliant_ implementation ;) The standard allows it so even if no such particular implementation would exist today, it could exist tomorrow. The fact that this possible implementation still stands today (while others like COW strings are now forbidden) tells me that there is at least one important implementation out there that uses it, perhaps one for an embedded processor... but just guessing here

Comment: @K-ballo, what sane implementer would make `c_str` a slow operation when it's so common? That's why I ask - just because it *could* exist doesn't mean it *does*, or ever will. I really wouldn't worry about it until I came across a counter-example.

Comment: @PaulH nope, it's necessary, because `strncpy` does not automatically append a `\0` if it has reached the end of the allocated size.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - `strncpy` seems to be about twice as fast as `std::string::copy` in my testing. So, you win!

Comment: To elaborate on @Mark Ransom's comment: According to [`stdncpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/), "If the end of the source C string (which is signaled by a null-character) is found before num characters have been copied, destination is padded with zeros until a total of num characters have been written to it." That is, it always fills the destination buffer up to the specified size, even when the source string is shorter.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that `dest_size` is guaranteed to be at least 1 (which seems reasonable to me, since otherwise it is not possible to copy and null terminate anything into the buffer):

```
inline void CopyAndNullTerminate( const std::string& source, 
                                  char* dest, 
                                  size_t dest_size )
{
    dest[source.copy(dest, dest_size-1)] = 0;
}
```

In C++11, and in all actively-maintained C++03 implementations (including Visual Studio), `std::string` has contiguous storage, just like `std::vector`. Thus, you could use `memcpy` instead of `std::string::copy` and compare performance.

Likewise you can compare `strncpy`, `std::copy`, `std::copy_n`, `strcpy_s`, and possibly others I've forgotten, see which is best optimized. In each case, you can compute the number of bytes to copy as `std::min(source.size(), dest_size-1)`. That also avoids the most inefficient case of `strncpy` (copying a small string into a large buffer).

When doing all these, you can rely on the fact that it *is* valid to call `source[0]` even if `source` is an empty string.

Answer (score 5):

If you initialize your destination string (to null) first, then you can get it will be null terminated if you don't overwrite the last element in your array.

```
enum{ MAX_STRING_SIZE = 15 };

char dest[ MAX_STRING_SIZE ] = {0}; // all elements are initialized to 0
std::string test = "This is a test";

// determine the length to copy, it will be the min of MAX_STRING_SIZE-1 
// or test.size.  This will ensure that even if the string it shorter than
// the MAX_STRING_SIZE, that it will copy properly -- without reading past the
// array bounds of the string.
auto copy_len = std::min(test.size(), MAX_STRING_SIZE - 1);

std::copy(
   test.begin(),
   test.begin() + copy_len,
   dest);
```

This will copy *at most* 14 characters to your `dest` object.  If the test string is shorter than 14 characters, it will only copy the length of the test string.  All elements not copied will remain at their initialized value (null).

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple that are shorter:

```
inline void CopyAndNullTerminate( const std::string& source, 
                                  char* dest, 
                                  size_t dest_size )
{
    *dest = '\0'; // assumes `dest_size > 0`
    strncat(dest, source, dest_size);
}

void CopyAndNullTerminate(std::string const &source,
                          char *dest,
                          size_t dest_size) { 
    sprintf(dest, "%*s", dest_size, source.c_str());
}
```

Efficient may be open to more question, but I don't see any reason to believe either will be particularly slow.

Answer (score 1):

How about the good ole' C strcpy_s?

```
strcpy_s(dest, MAX_STRING_SIZE, test.c_str());
```

I prefer this to `strncpy`. The `strcpy_s` (and it's older cousin `strlcpy`) copy loop will terminate after copying the '\0', but `strncpy` will always write out the number of bytes specified (padding with '\0' if the source string is shorter).

Comment: Unfortunately, `strlcpy` is not a part of the C standard, it is a BSD function, as far as I can tell, and will not be available in VS 2008.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, BTW, the reason I prefer those functions is that `strncpy` always writes out the number of bytes specified in the third parameter, and doesn't null terminate if the source string is longer than the bytes specified.

Comment: @user315052 - The _s functions don't silently truncate. They explode with unhappiness instead.